# How to transfer node.js results to HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to use SQL server and nodejs with my HTML file.

I'm connecting with my database with nodejs using mssql and hapijs, and i can obtain my table in json format, but i dont know how to obtain this information on my HTML.

Also, how can i make the server update from HTML?

Here is my nodejs code:

```
var http = require("http");


getData = function(callback){
    var sql = require('mssql');

    //Data Connection
    sql.connect("mssql://username:password@localhost\\SQLEXPRESS/CrudExample?encrypt:true").then(function() {
        // Query 
        new sql.Request().query('select * from MOCK_DATA').then(function(recordset) {
            //console.dir(recordset);
            callback(recordset)
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Length": results.length});
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            response.end(results);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // ... query error checks 
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // ... connect error checks 
        console.log('Error en la consulta')
        console.log(err)
    });
}

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');

// Create a server with a host and port
const server = new Hapi.Server({
    connections: {
        routes: {
            files: {
                relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
            }
        }
    }
});


server.connection({ 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 8000 
});

// Add the route


// Start the server
server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path:'/getTable', 
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            getData(function(r) {return reply(r)})

        }
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path:'/', 
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply("hello world")
        }
    });

    server.start((err) => {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can do this with an ajax request

Comment: Thanks but I'm very new at this, can you please give me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `handlebars` as a view engine

refer to http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views